# Flatten a java project directory structure prepending the path to the file

Tags: bash, scripting, directory, flatten

I am trying to write a script (preferably in bash) to flatten a java projet directory structure prepending the path to the file. Example:

```
| src
  | org
    | apache
      | file2.java
    | file1.java
```

would result in:

```
| src
  | org|apache|file2.java
  | org|file1.java
```

The script should be recursive since the directory could have many subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd src
for i in $(find . - name '*.java') ; do 
  echo cp \"$i\" $(echo "$i" | tr / _)
done
```

if it looks good(might barf if filenames contains spaces), pipe the result to `sh`

Comment: Is it possible for a java file name to have spaces?

Comment: By the way, when i Removed the first echo and the quotes from the $i variable and ran the script it didn't do anything.

Comment: `find ... | while read -r i` instead of `for ... find` will work if filenames have spaces.

Comment: How would I adapt to your solution?